# SQL Server 2008 - date format issue while inserting

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert date into a table but the date and format of inserted date is messed up. The datatype in the table is `Date`. My insert script is as below.

```
insert into Trans(ID, TDate, Description)
values(1, CONVERT(datetime, 25-02-2012, 101), 'Opening')
```

I am trying to insert in `dd/MM/yyyy` format and I want it in the same format in my table. But in my table the date is `1894-07-22` !!

I want the date to be inserted exactly as the format I wish and I want to see the inserted date as `25-02-2012` in the table.

What is wrong here ? Can somebody help ?

Comment: You should use the ISO format (`YYYYMMDD` - **no** dashes or anything!) which is language and date settings indepedent and works on every instance of SQL Server. Also: SQL Server **does not** store dates in any particular string-based format - it's stored as 8 byte binary data. All you see is a **string representation** of that `DATE` stored - you **cannot** store it in a particular format - a `DATE` is a `DATE` is a `DATE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `CONVERT(datetime ,'25-02-2012', 103)`

- use some single quotes around the value
- choose your format accordingly (101 is US, meaning mm/dd/yyyy)
- see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.100).aspx for more details

Answer (score 0):

you should use single quotes around your date. If you want date format of `dd/mm/yyyy` format then you will want to use the convert(datetime, '25-02-2012', 103)

```
insert into Trans(ID,TDate,Description)
values(1,CONVERT(datetime,'25-02-2012',103),'Opening')
```

if you use `convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)` the format of the date will be `mm/dd/yyyy`.

There are several helpful links to use as a reference for datetime conversions:

- [How to format datetime & date](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)
- [Tips & tricks SQL Server Date formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Comment: convert(char(10)),'25-02-2012',103) gives error as my table field type is of datetime.

Answer (score -1):

```
insert into emp
(EMPNO,ENAME,DEPTNO,JOB,SAL,COMM,MGR,HIREDATE)values
 (7839,'KING',10,'PRESIDENT',5000,NULL,NULL,'17-11-81')
```

Comment: What does this answer even have to do with the question?